# parsing Block using flex and bison

Tags: parsing, block, flex-lexer, bisonc++

Is it possible to parse Block through flex and bison??

Example:

Suppose

```
BEGIN BLOCK BLK_ROWDEC
            NAME                          cell_rowdec
            SIZE                          UNI_rowdecSize
            ITERATE                       itr_rows
            DIRECTION                     lgDir_rowdec
            STRAP                         STRD1,STRD3,STRD2
            WRAP                          WRD1
            VIA                           VIAB,VIAC,VIAD
ENDS BLK_ROWDEC
```

Now I want to check Is BEGIN and END is belong to same block or not?/Is it possible with flex and bison

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, just save the block name with the BEGIN and check it when you get the END.

But the block name is redundant here, and Bison will match up begins and ends automatically. If you can remove it from your syntax I would do so.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you give me example.

Comment: An END matches up to the nearest prior BEGIN that isn't already matched. Just like IF and ELSE, or { and }.

Comment: No it is not match. And I have to generate error if BLOCK name is different means BLOCK name of BEGIN and ENDS are different. So how can it is possible with FLEX and BISON.

Comment: Err, yes it does match. If you have to retain the block names and generate an erro on mismatches, you have to do what it says in my answer, but it hardly seems worthwhile with this trivial syntax. This is no place for a Bison tutorial.

Comment: can you please explain via example??please.. I am new to flex and bison so